# Parsing user name and password from binary in Erlang + Cowboy

Tags: erlang, websocket

I am working on a web app that uses a WebSocket to log in users. I would like to minimize bandwidth usage by using binary messages. I came up with the following, and would like to know whether there is something better I could be doing:

```
-define(LOGIN, 1).

websocket_handle({binary, <<?LOGIN:8,LengthUser:8, Rest/bitstring>>}, Req, State) ->
    LU2 = LengthUser*8,
    <<Username:LU2/bitstring, Password/bitstring>> = Rest,
    % Do the actual logging in...
```

I did a decent amount of research, and couldn't find a way to avoid using the `Rest` piece in order to accommodate variable length bitstring patterns. The web app uses an `ArrayBuffer` and a few `DataView`s in order to construct the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is necessary because of the need to extract the length of the `Username` field before using it to extract the `Username` field itself. However, you needn't use `bitstring` anywhere because you're only sending whole bytes, not bitfields. You can change all occurrences of `bitstring` to `binary` instead, and with that change you also no longer need to specify the length of `Username` in bits, so you no longer need `LU2` and can just use `LengthUser` directly:

```
-define(LOGIN, 1).

websocket_handle({binary, <<?LOGIN:8,LengthUser:8, Rest/binary>>}, Req, State) ->
    <<Username:LengthUser/binary, Password/binary>> = Rest,
    %% Do the actual logging in...
```

And finally, note that by convention, Erlang comments on a line by themselves at the current indentation level start with `%%`, not `%`. Single `%` should be used only for end-of-line comments. Not sure about other editors but the emacs `erlang-mode` indents comments this way, so if an emacs user worked on your code your comments might get wildly indented if the emacs developer auto-indented the buffer and didn't check everything afterwards.